# Error in cucumber tests "no such file to load -- rspec (MissingSourceFile)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, rspec-rails

I install the bundle using the command

**bundle install**

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Using RubyInline (3.10.0) 

Using activesupport (2.3.10) 

Using activerecord (2.3.10) 

Using rspec (1.3.1) 

Using selenium-webdriver (2.18.0) 

Using xpath (0.1.4) 

Using capybara (1.1.2) 

Using cucumber (0.9.4) 

Using cucumber-rails (0.3.2) 

Using email_spec (0.6.6) 

Using erubis (2.7.0) 

Using ruby_core_source (0.1.5) 

Using mysql2 (0.2.18) 

Using rails (2.3.10) 

Using rspec-rails (1.3.3)  

Using thinking-sphinx (1.4.10) 
...

Using bundler (1.0.21)
```

**Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./rspec-mail**

I also tried **bundle install .**

but when I run **my cucumber test**, I have this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

**no such file to load -- rspec (MissingSourceFile)**

which I didnt have in the past! 
Any ideas?
Thanks